# Does each discrete solvable group admit an injective homomorphism to a compact topological group?

Tags: topological-groups

It is well-known that each abelian group admits an injective homomorphism to some compact topological group (for example to its [Bohr compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_compactification)). Is the same fact true for solvable groups?

**Question 1.** Does every solvable group admit an injective homomorphism to a compact Hausdorff topological group?

Equivalently:

**Question 2.** Is the Bohr topology of every discrete solvable group Hausdorff?

The *Bohr topology* is the largest totally bounded group topology on the group.

Comment: No. A finitely generated group admits an injective homomorphism to a compact group iff it's residually finite. There exist finitely generated solvable groups that are not residually finite.

Comment: @YCor: Is there a reference (or short explanation) for this criterion? The "if" direction is clear, but I don't immediately see why the converse holds.

Comment: I think this should work: compact (Hausdorff)  groups are pro-(matrix Lie groups) by the Peter-Weyl theorem, and finitely generated subgroups of pro-(matrix Lie groups) are residually finite by Malcev's theorem.

Comment: @VictorProtsak Qiaochu's right: Peter-Weyl + Malcev. For the existence of such solvable groups: two such families appeared in the 50's: f.g. groups solvable whose center is isomorphic to the non-residually-finite abelian group $\mathbf{Z}[1/p]/\mathbf{Z}$ (Ph. Hall), or Gruenberg, who proved that every wreath product $H\wr\mathbf{Z}$ for $H$ an arbitrary non-abelian group, is non-residually-finite.

Comment: @YCor Thank you for the answer. In fact, I need a positive answer to a very special case of Questions 1,2 for solvable groups which are finite-by-abelian, i.e., solvable groups with finite commutator group. Does any solvable finite-by-abelian group admit an injective homomorphism to a compact topological group? In this case for finite-generated finite-by-abelian groups the answer is "yes".

Comment: f.g. finite-by-abelian groups are virtually abelian (= abelian-by-finite) and hence residually finite. More generally virtually nilpotent f.g. groups are residually finite. This is well documented (certainly in Derek Robinson's Springer GTM book).

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the answer. I have just found your (negative) answer to another question that interested me: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146656/finitely-generated-solvable-groups-all-of-whose-abelian-normal-subgroups-are-fin

Comment: @YCor But maybe each infinite solvable group contains an infinite Bohr separated normal subgroup? (A group $G$ is Bohr separated if it admits an injective homomorphiusm to a compact topological group).

Comment: You always have an infinite normal subgroup with a homomorphism with finite kernel to a compact group (namely the last infinite term in the derived series). But if I'm correct, my construction in the post you link (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146656/) is also a f.g. solvable group in which no infinite normal subgroup $N$ is Bohr-separated. Indeed $N$ contains a 2-nilpotent, non-residually-finite subgroup of finite exponent. If it were inside a compact group, the closure would have finite exponent, hence would be a profinite group, and hence would be residually finite, contradiction.

Comment: @YCor Merci beaucoup. So, the life is more complicatied as I expected :(

Comment: @YCor By the way, is the group in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146656 non-topologizable? So, is it an example of a solvable non-topologizable group?

Comment: @YCor Sorry for the preceding question, I fould in a paper of Dikranjan and Toller (2010) that each countable solvable group is topologizable, so your group is topologizable, too.

Comment: In the case of my example, it even has a dense embedding into a (Hausdorff, totally disconnected) locally compact group, if I'm correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Proposition 3.3 from Dikranjan and Toller [Topology and its Applications 159 (2012) 2951-2972], the Heisenberg group H_K over an infinite field K of characteritic 0 is not maximally almost periodic. This provides
a negative answer to the question even for nilpotent groups of class 2.

Comment: The char 0 case was well-known before. Indeed, consider a homomorphism of $H_3(K)$ into a compact Lie group. Since $H_3(K)$ has no finite proper quotient as abstract group, the closure $G$ of the image is connected; as a connected nilpotent compact Lie group, it is abelian. So by Peter-Weyl, every homomorphism from $H_3(K)$ to a compact group has abelian image.

Comment: The char $p$ case, possibly well-known too, is by a distinct argument. First, we see that since a compact Lie group of bounded exponent is finite and using Peter-Weyl, a group of finite exponent is maximally almost periodic if and only if it's residually finite. Then whether these kinds of 2-nilpotent groups are residually finite has probably been considered early; anyway it's less obvious than in char. 0.

Comment: Here's the argument that $H=H_3(K)$ is not RF (and hence not MAP) in char $p$, namely every finite quotient is abelian. Otherwise there exists a finite index subgroup $N$, intersecting the center $Z$ in a proper subgroup $M$. Enlarging $M$, we can suppose that $M$ has index $p$ in $Z$. For a contradiction, let's show that $Z/M$ has abelian image in every finite quotient of $H/M$. The commutator (valued in $Z/M$) yields an alternating $Z/pZ$-bilinear form $b$ on $V=H/Z$. This form has trivial kernel, because in $H$ the map $y\mapsto [x,y]$ is surjective for any fixed $x\neq 0$ in $V$. (...)

Comment: Hence there exist infinite sequences $(x_n)$, $(y_n)$ in $V$ such that $b(x_n,y_n)\neq 0$ (in $H/M$) while $b(x_n,x_m)=0$ for all $n,m$ and $b(x_n,y_m)=0$ for all $n\neq m$. Inside any finite quotient $F$ of $H/M$ in which $Z/M$ is preserved, these properties still hold. But on the other hand, they imply that in the quotient $F/(Z/M)$ of $V$, the family $(x_n)$ is linearly free (over $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$). It contradicts that $F$ is finite.